# R function to loop through global environment

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, xts

I have 70+ objects in my global environment of the class data.frame, with names A, B, C, D and so on. Each of these has different number of rows and three columns, where the first one is date. I want to apply the following function to each of them:

```
A$date<-as.Date(A$date)
A.xts<-xts(A[,2:3], order.by = A$date)
```

Is there any way to construct a for loop that goes through every object in the global environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can get all the objects into a `list` with `mget` (assuming that we are loading all the objects from the working space and all are data.frames) and then apply a function

```
library(xts)
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls()), f1)
```

NOTE: In `ls`, we can pass `patterns` as well.  Suppose, if the dataseet objects are named 'df1', 'df2', etc

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$')), f1)
```

If we really wanted to create multiple objects, use `list2env` (not recommended)

```
names(lst1) <- paste0(names(lst1), '_new')
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

where

```
f1 <- function(x) { x$date <- as.Date(x$date)
              xts(x[,2:3], order.by = x$date)
            }
```

Comment: Seems to be working, however, I need to create 70+ variables with the names A.xts and so on, the code you provided only returns it in console, but doesn't create the variables in global environment

Comment: @AdamUhliarik It is a `list` object and you can extract the single xts objecst as `lst1[[1]]`, `lst1[[2]]`, I would not recommend to create multiple objects in the global env.  YOu can check my update where I assigned to `lst1 <-`